# CSS Top Padding in IE9

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-9

I have a CSS similar to the one below.

```
.ui-icon {
    font-size: 6em;
   height: 180px;
   width: 180px;
}

.ui-icon .ui-icon-label {
    padding-top: 15%;
}
```

The top padding doesn't display the text in IE9 (i.e. ui-icon-label).

HTML is also given below.

```
<div class="ui-icon-color ui-icon">
<div id="icon-1">
<i class="icon-cog"></i>
</div>
<div class="ui-icon-label">My Label</div>
</div>
```

But the same code works well in Chrome and Firefox. IE9 displays the ui-icon-label till the padding is 13.4%. Till the value, when I increase it gradually the text moves downwards a bit. Above that value it suddenly disappears. But For me 15% looks the best position to place the label. I went through different solutions provided in the suggest like 'clear:both' or using the W3C validator. But they didn't help.

FYI, the icon-cog class comes from font-awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a IE9 targeted stylesheet with media queries to solve that issue?

```
 <!--[if IE 9]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie9.css" />
 <![endif]-->

 // In the CSS:

 @media (max-width: ???px) {
     .ui-icon .ui-icon-label {
        padding-top: 30%;
     }
 }
```

Comment: I dont think there is a need for media query. However the pointer is in the right direction. Thanks. That helps.